AJS.params.baseURL returning wrong base URL ( HTTP instead of HTTPS )
I am using JIRA v9.11.3
The application is running in K8s behind reverse proxy.
When I access https://[MyDomain]/jira/secure/InsightReportManager.jspa
The page tries to access
http://[MyDomain]/jira/rest/insight-widgets/1/user/configuration
Because it is getting the BaseUrl from riada.api.baseURL which in-turn get the base URL from AJS.params.baseURL
I have already configured my Jira base URL to HTTPS and all other pages works fine. What went wrong? Thank you a lot!


Found the answer. Configuring only the Jira Base Url inside Jira Setting is not enough. The Tomcat server configuation / environent variable itself must be re-configured.
  - ATL_PROXY_NAME=
  - ATL_PROXY_PORT=
  - ATL_TOMCAT_PORT=
  - ATL_TOMCAT_SCHEME=
  - ATL_TOMCAT_CONTEXTPATH=/jira

Must be changed to
  secure="true"
  scheme="https"
  proxyName="YourDomain"
  proxyPort="443"

